# How to determine if given string is a hostname or an IP address

Tags: go

```
_, err := strconv.ParseInt(host, 10, 64)
if err == nil {
    hp.IpAddress = host           
} else {            
    hp.HostName = dbhost 
}
```

With host = sealinuxvm11 I'm getting

```
error strconv.ParseInt: parsing " sealinuxvm11 ": invalid syntax
```

and with host = 192.168.24.10

```
strrconv.ParseInt: parsing " 192.168.24.10": invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 16):

An IP Address should be parsed as a string. I use the net package's `ParseIP` to determine whether a given string is an IP or a host

```golang
addr := net.ParseIP(host)
if addr != nil {
    hp.IPAddress = host
} else {
    hp.HostName = host
}
```

However, this may set hostname with an invalid value. Check to make sure that host name is a valid host name if `net.ParseIP` returns an error. Would use

```golang
hostName, err := net.LookupHost(host)
if len(hostName) > 0{
    if hostName[0] == hp.HostName{
    }
}
```

to determine if the host name is valid

Like [@kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) pointed out in comments there are definitely better and faster ways to determine if a host name is valid. I recommend you do some research into how that can be achieved.

Comment: I'd advise against using `net.LookupHost()` for verification purposes: this funciton is not pure: it has potentially extensive side-effects (imagine checking 100000 hostnames for validity in a tight loop). In fact, checking whether a hostname is valid is simple (a character-by-character iterator combined with a smlple state machine; I'd say it will be under 100 lines of code).

Comment: Basically the hostname format defined by [RFC 952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc952) and refined by [RFC 1123](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1123#page-13) which laxed the definition a bit. The former defines the following grammar for hostnames: `<hname> ::= <name>*["."<name>]` and `<name>  ::= <let>[*[<let-or-digit-or-hyphen>]<let-or-digit>]` plus the size requirements of supporting hostnames from 63 to 255 octets in length. I'd say implementing a parser for the two rules above is not hard.

Comment: is an ip address not a valid hostname? why must the first character in `name` be `<let>`?

Comment: @brianSan An IP address is a represents a logical network location label which can be used in the TCP/IP layers.
Whereas a hostname always has to be resolved as an IP from DNS Servers to establish an IP connection.

Comment: I always resolve the raw input and get an ip in output.